# Getting Error: error: type "double" does not exist while loading a cube js dashboard

Tags: javascript, postgresql, caching, dashboard, cube.js

While running my cube js dashboard I could only load values in some parts of the dashboard while others values were not loaded. Rather they were giving error: `error: type "double" does not exist.`

After this, for the dashboard to load all the values I had to comment out the preaggregation part in my schema.js file (A file where we define all SQL queries, measures, dimensions, and pre-aggregations).

After disabling pre-aggregation all values loaded. But I want to achieve this with pre-aggregation as well.
Adding to the above, I am fetching data from Athena and using Postgres for pre-aggregation.

I was trying to load all values in the dashboard with pre-aggregation but got the above error. I was only able to load the whole dashboard with all values when the pre-aggregation part was commented out in the schema.js file. I want to achieve with pre-aggregation also.

Comment: Have you checked that the right datatype for  double exist or is specified in your schema.js? Share your commented preaggregation part of code.